# ng build issue : Could not find plugin "proposal-class-properties"

Tags: angular-cli, ng-build

i got this issue when i try to run the command ng build, i think the problem related to babel but i can't find any guide or solution for this problem anyone has encoutered this issue before?
here is the log

```
[error] Error: [BABEL] C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\dist\AdminLTE\modules-auth-auth-module-es2015.js: Could not find plugin "proposal-class-properties". Ensure there is an entry in ./available-plugins.js for it. (While processing: "C:\\Users\\Yas-stud\\Desktop\\novo\\xtree_0\\Frond_end\\node_modules\\@babel\\preset-env\\lib\\index.js")
    at getPlugin (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:67:11)
    at C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:258:62
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\preset-env\lib\index.js:258:43
    at C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\helper-plugin-utils\lib\index.js:19:12
    at C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\config\full.js:179:14
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at Function.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:26:3)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at step (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\gensync\index.js:254:32)
    at evaluateAsync (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\gensync\index.js:284:5)
    at Function.errback (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\gensync\index.js:108:7)
    at errback (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\@babel\core\lib\gensync-utils\async.js:70:18)
    at async (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\gensync\index.js:183:31)
    at onFirstPause (C:\Users\Yas-stud\Desktop\novo\xtree_0\Frond_end\node_modules\gensync\index.js:209:13)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: run npm i command and then make build

Comment: it didn't work, i think the problem is i got some dot files

Comment: yeah i found the solution: i deleted node modules folder because i found dot files in it